# Mercurial ssh authentication whenpush

Tags: mercurial

I am trying to make a push using mercurial to a repo on Bitbucket. I made sure to copy correctly the ssh key from `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to my bitbucket account.

```
cat .hg/hgrc  
[paths]
default = ssh://bitbucket.org/mcarey/arakoon
```

Still when pushing I got this error:

```
pushing to ssh://bitbucket.org/mcarey/arakoon  
remote: Permission denied (publickey).  
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

I would assume the problem is as the repo shall be

```
ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/mcarey/arakoon
```

Is this correct? If so how to modify it? If not, what is it about?

Answer (score 2):

Just edit .hg/hgrc:

```
[paths]
default = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/YOURNAME/REPONAME
```

Comment: The key piece there is the username needs to be `hg`, so `hg@` goes in.

Comment: prompted windows for password then this output                               remote: conq: repository does not exist.
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!

Answer (score 1):

Ok. important to note the following

hg@ before the bitbucket.org/YOURNAME/REPONAME

YOURNAME shall be the name in the repo not the user name. the username is attached in the SSH key or HTTPS username/password.

These were my problems. Its solved now